# cant get the model value in template

Tags: ember.js

just started to play with emberjs.dont know if this is stupid question or good one, but I am stuck in this for some days and cant figure out why.

in my router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', {path: '/'});
  ..........
  });

  .....
  this.resource('post', {path: 'posts/:post_id'});
});
```

and in the route folder i have posts.js setup as following.it has simple js  varible used to hold id , title, and body of articles.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
         var posts = [
        {
        id:'1',
        title:'lipsome vesicle',
        body:"A liposome is a spherical vesicle"},      
        {
        id:'2',
        title:'another lipsome vesicle',
        body:"A liposome is a another vesicle"}
]
    //console.log(posts)
        return posts;
    }
});
```

In posts.hbs, the title of each post is shown as link to the to post. of course by looping through **each model as |post| and print link-to post.title.**

my post.js file simply get the model for posts and returns it.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {

        return this.modelFor('posts').findBy('id', params.post_id);
    }
});
```

In my template for post.hbs I wanted to simply show the title and body for the post .It  would have been more redable if it was like post.title or something like that. but i saw some tutorials that does following.

```
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h1>{{body}}</h1>
```

the url goes to the localhost:4200/post/1 
but I cannot see the title and body

when I checked the value in console for

```
 this.modelFor('posts').findBy('id', params.post_id).title , it prints the title
```

but view is blank.
I have read somewhere, that the controller is the one that is responsible to get the value from model. in that case too, I dont know how to access the returned model in that controller.

I have watched many tutorials, including the raffler example by railscast, since I have background in rails. but those tuts including lot other seems preety outdated. So *for all new learners* this is frustating and confusing too. **Is there good fresh resources except the emberjs guide?**

Answer (score 0):

since the title was being printed in console, after many trials when i tried this trick, i finally managed to get my title in individual post.using Ember inspector plug in when i clicked $E console gave me all the post.so i put that object in array and returned that array.

```
model: function(params) {
        // console.log("hell")
         console.log(this.modelFor('posts').findBy('id', params.post_id).title);
         var post = [this.modelFor('posts').findBy('id', params.post_id)];
        return post;
    }
```

then in my view I looped through the array as:

```
<ul>
    {{#each model as |post|}}
        <li>{{post.title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

but I would like to know better way for this.